# Keep doubles slashes in mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I try to rewrite urls like:
http://www.example.com/contoller/method/var1/var2/var3
to
http://www.example.com/index.php?q=contoller/method/var1/var2/var3

**My rewrite rules are as below:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It works well except with doubles slashes. Indeed, there are replaced by singles slashes.

I would like to be able to use it when a var is empty. For example, if the var2 is empty the URL contains a double slashes on the var2 location

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The URL you're corrupting in the query string is already available within `index.php` as `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.